# continue the incrementation of the figures

Tags: graphics, floats, numbering

I have a global file that contains two other files,like this :

```
input{part1/chap1} input{part1/chap2}
```

so i have 2 figures one in "chap1" and the second in "chap2"
in "chap1" my figure is : figure 1 
and in "chap2" my other figure is also figure 1 
I want my figure which is located in "chap2" be figure 2 not figure 1 
Thank youu

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This is default behaviour, the counter is reset on a new chapter, but normally the number should be "figure 1.1" in chapter 1. Please create a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050).

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}` before `\begin{document}` ... and this is a clear duplicate ... we have a question like this basically every day ...